# JS works fine in jsFiddle but not in my dust.js template

Tags: jquery, dust.js

I have some simple javascript code that I have tested in JS Fiddle which works fine there, but when using in my dust.js template, i keep getting "unexpected token ILLEGAL" but it doesnt tell me which token is illegal. I've checked for extra characters already.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit').keydown(function(e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
        $(this).blur().next().focus();
       return false;
  }

  });
})​
```

Here is the jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sxvX8/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extra character at the end, see below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            $(this).blur().next().focus();
           return false;
        }    
    });
})? // <--- EXTRA CHARACTER
```

Remove it and that error should go away.

Comment: Are you referring to the bracket?

Comment: No, i'm referring to the `?` it's invisible in your code, but you can make it appear by pasting the code into notepad++ or similar editor.

Comment: I do apologise, but i don't see any extra "?" anywhere in my js code or the rendered dust.js template? Sorry If i'm coming across rather naive, I'm a little confused.

Comment: That's the point, it's invisible. It only shows up as a ? to me because it is a character that is not recognized by notepad++. In your editor it simply shows as    (it's invisible and doesn't take up space). Copy my code, remove the `? //<---...` at the end, and try it. I'm sure you'll see the difference. Make sure you also delete the empty lines *around* this code to ensure you don't miss the invisible character.

Comment: Amazing. I had no idea that could be an issue! Thank you for putting up with me.